# Create an owner group firstly include the site current user and assign permissions full control to it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, groups, solution-package, feature-activation

i have used this code but when i deploy nothing changes :

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;

            if (site != null)
            {
                SPWeb topLevelSite = site.RootWeb;
                string webAppRelativePath = topLevelSite.ServerRelativeUrl;
                if (!webAppRelativePath.EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    webAppRelativePath += "/";
                }
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    // Activate the publishing feature for all webs.
                    web.MasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage/-collabspace.master";
                    web.CustomMasterUrl = webAppRelativePath + "_catalogs/masterpage-collabspace.master";
                    web.SiteLogoUrl = "/Style%20Library/labspace/images/-logo.jpg";


                    string groupName = "Ma-SolCollab";
                    string groupDescription = "Group for CollabSol";
                    try
                    {

                        CreateSubSiteGroup(SPContext.Current.Web, groupName, "Full Control", groupDescription);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string message = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
}


 private static void CreateSubSiteGroup(SPWeb web, string groupName, string PermissionLevel, string groupDescription)
        {
            SPUserCollection users = web.AllUsers;
            SPUser owner = web.SiteAdministrators[0];
            SPMember member = web.SiteAdministrators[0];
            SPGroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;
            groups.Add(groupName, member, owner, groupDescription);
            SPGroup newSPGroup = groups[groupName];
            SPRoleDefinition role = web.RoleDefinitions[PermissionLevel];
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(newSPGroup);
            roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(role);
            web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            web.Update();
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SPContext.Current inside FeatureActivated function
cmd.exe process does not understand or know how to get your current context! If you are running via browser, you have the w3wp.exe process from which you can get the context!

Since you have your web defined in 
foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)

pass the same in CreateSubSiteGroup(web, groupName, "Full Control", groupDescription);